# Understanding returning from procs in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, internals

I was wondering how to pass a block to a method which will make the method `return` on `yield`.

The naive aproach doesn't work:

```
def run(&block)
  block.call
end

run { return :foo } # => LocalJumpError
```

Wrapping in another proc has the same effect:

```
def run(&block)
  proc { block.call }.call
end

run { return :bar } # => LocalJumpError
```

So I thought that the `return` statement is bound to the `receiver` of the current `binding`. However, trying it out with `instance_eval` proved me wrong:

```
class ProcTest
  def run(&block)
    puts "run: #{[binding.local_variables, binding.receiver]}"
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

pt = ProcTest.new
binding_inspector = proc { puts "proc: #{[binding.local_variables, binding.receiver]}" }
puts "main: #{[binding.local_variables, binding.receiver]}"
    # => main: [[:pt, :binding_inspector], main]
binding_inspector.call
    # => proc: [[:pt, :binding_inspector], main]
pt.run(&binding_inspector)
    # => run: [[:block], #<ProcTest:0x007f4987b06508>]
    # => proc: [[:pt, :binding_inspector], #<ProcTest:0x007f4987b06508>]
pt.run { return :baz }
    # => run: [[:block], #<ProcTest:0x007f4987b06508>]
    # => LocalJumpError
```

So the questions are:

1. How can this be done?
2. How is the return context tied to the `return` statement. Is this connection accessible via the language's API?
3. Was this implemented in such manner intentionally? If yes - why? If no - what are the obstacles to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

> I thought that the `return` statement is bound to the `receiver` of the current `binding`.

Only *methods* have an receiver. `return` is not a method:

```
defined? return #=> "expression"
```

Trying to invoke it as a method doesn't work:

```
def foo
  send(:return, 123)
end

foo #=> undefined method `return'
```

> trying it out with `instance_eval` proved me wrong

Though `instance_eval` evaluates the block in the context of the receiver (so you have access to the receivers instance methods and instance variables):

```
class MyClass
   def foo(&block)
     @var = 123
     instance_eval(&block)
   end
end

MyClass.new.foo { instance_variables }
#=> [:@var]
```

... it does *not* evaluate the block in the current binding (so you don't have access to any local variables):

```
class MyClass
   def foo(&block)
     var = 123
     instance_eval(&block)
   end
end

MyClass.new.foo { local_variables }
#=> []
```

> How can this be done?

You could use `eval`, but that requires a string:

```
def foo
  var = 123
  eval yield
  nil
end

foo { "return var * 2" }
#=> 246
```

Or by passing the binding to the block (again using `eval`):

```
def foo
  var = 123
  yield binding
  nil
end

foo { |b| b.eval "return var * 2" }
#=> 246
```

Comment: eval is probably the best solution here, since the code gets eval'd in the scope of the yielding method, but `eval yield` seems incredibly dangerous; `yield binding` is probably the best appropach. Be aware that this code will get parsed, compiled into an iseq, and then executed on every invocation, which may be less than stellar WRT performance - I bench it at around 100k IPS - an order of magnitude slower than a block operation not involving an eval.

Comment: @ChrisHeald attempting to invoke `return` from outside a method is probably not the best idea in the first place ;-)

Comment: My thinking was that *proc* invocation should just add the *proc* body to the current stack and returning from that *proc* should return up the stack to the last thing in the stack (aka the method that called it). Since this is not the case, I thought that the place from which the `return` would be fired should be stored somewhere. `block.binding.receiver` seemed logical. And even though `instance_eval` doesn't completely replace the binding, it changes it (as seen - the `receiver` is different).

Comment: So the only option is that the context from which the *proc* will *return* is stored in some part of the `block.binding`, which is not modified by `instance_eval`. Did I get it right so far? If yes - is this part of the *binding* accessible via the language API? Also I still don't see what is the problem to access and *return* from the *binding* of the place where you are called (being a *proc*).

Comment: *"is this part of the binding accessible"* - well, somehow via `b.eval` as shown in my last example.

Answer (score 1):

`return` in a block returns from the enclosing method when the block is defined (ie, the closure in which the block is created). In your example, there is no enclosing block to return from, hence your exception.

This is easily demonstrated:

```
def foo(&block)
  puts yield
  puts "we won't get here"
end

def bar
  foo { return "hi from the block"; puts "we never get here" }
  puts "we never get here either"
end

puts bar # => "hi from the block" (only printed once; the puts in `foo` is not executed)
```

Return in a proc will immediately return out of the proc, not out of the method on the stack under the proc:

```
def foo(&block)
  puts yield
  puts "we will get here"
end

def bar
  foo &->{ return "hi from the proc"; puts "we never get here" }
  puts "we will get here too"
end

puts bar
# hi from the proc      # puts from foo
# we will get here      # puts from foo
# we will get here too  # puts from bar
```

Because of these behaviors, there is no way to achieve your desired behavior, in which a `return` in the given block will execute a `return` in the method from which the block is invoked, unless the block was defined within that scope, since doing so would require one of the existing behaviors not work.

You could achieve something like this with throw...catch, which is kinda-sorta useful as a way to zip up the stack from an arbitrary depth, but you can't return arbitrary values with it:

```
def foo(&block)
  yield
  puts "we won't get here"
end

catch(:escape) do
  foo &->{ throw :escape }
end
```

Comment: You didn't answer a single question. The first point - I know that I'm getting the exception because I'm trying to `return` from the *main* scope and that the `return` is tied to the scope which defined it. About the second part - I know *lambdas* have different `return` semantics from regular *procs*, the question wasn't about them. I also know about `throw` - `catch`, the question was about understanding `return`. It's like asking *why is the grass green?* and getting an answer *looking at this grass, you can see that it's green, water isn't green and you can paint fake grass in non-green*.

Comment: There is no facility to Ruby to pass a block to a method which can return from within the block out of the method the block was passed to because such return behavior would be mutually exclusive with existing return behaviors. I don't know *why* it was designed that way, but "why doesn't Ruby have this" is thus answered, and thus Q1 is answered (you can't), Q3 is thus irrelevant (it's not a bug to be fixed, it's an intentional selection of mutually-exclusive alternatives), Q2 will require getting into the parser and VM code to answer, but the answer is probably "the context is not exposed".

Comment: What do you mean by *because such return behavior would be mutually exclusive with existing return behaviors* and *intentional selection of mutually-exclusive alternatives*? What desired behavior would be broken if it was implemented to return from the calling method. Isn't the proc execution added to the stack when it is called? *why doesn't Ruby have this* implies that this is an additional feature, which is not.

Comment: `return` from a block returns from the frame in which the block was defined (which is stored as a copy of the frame on the block struct). You'd have to break this behavior to get your desired behavior, and it would violate Ruby's design of blocks for the block to have access to the frame of the method from which it's yielded rather than the closure in which it is defined. Perhaps you could elaborate on what you're attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how and why it works this way, there is no practical task to be accomplished here. It makes sense that the *proc* structure holds the *binding* of the context which created it, but I still don't see what is the problem to access and *return* from the *binding* of the place where it is called.

Comment: `return` in a block and a non-lambda `Proc` returns from the *enclosing* method, `return` in a method and a lambda returns from the method/lambda *itself*. Remember: `Proc` behaves like block, because they rhyme, lambda behaves like method, because they are both greek. :-D (The same is true for argument binding, BTW, `Proc`s bind arguments like blocks do, lambdas bind arguments like methods do.)